# Conflicting MVC RouteConig

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to add a new route in my RouteConfig.cs but it is only working if I remove one of the current route. Is there anyway around this? Is there a better way to do this ? should it key off of the RouteCollection?

Current

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirSearch", "fhir/{type}", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "Search" });
```

New

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirDiseasesList", "fhir/DiseasesList", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "DiseasesList" });
```

This also Conflicting

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirDiseasesList", "fhir/Diseases/List", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "DiseasesList" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it is only working if I remove one of the current route

I think both of your route works fine but what happens is the routing engine executes the route that is indicated first. So-- whichever route comes first that matches your url, that is the one that's going to be executed.

1. I think the easiest fix is to really change the route url. This depends entirely on you but make sure they don't have matching/clashing routes.

Like separate the word `diseases` and `list` in your new route.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirSearch", "fhir/Diseases/List", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "DiseasesList" });
```

2. If you really want to retain both routes, what you could do is-- in your Search action method, add a check if type == "DiseasesList" then redirect.

```
public ActionResult Search(string type)
{
   if(type == "DiseasesList"){
      return redirectToAction("DiseasesList");
   }

   ... // do something else
}
```

EDIT: OP mentioned without the specific routing, it would hit Search action

For `routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirRead", "fhir/{type}/{id}", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "Read" });` you could add a constraint to only match `id` with integers.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   "FhirRead",
   "fhir/{type}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Fhir", action = "Read" },
   new {id = @"\d+" } // routing constraint to only match id with integers
);
```

Comment: if I use the default route that is like removing the new route it will route to the incorrect ActionResult

Comment: @Jefferson oh I understand-- it would hit the search route if you didn't indicate. thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Jefferson can I get an upvote as well? Thank you :D

Comment: so there is no way to add this route without going into the search action method

Comment: why will it not get routed to the action when it has the route template name?

Comment: @Jefferson for `fhir/Diseases/List`, try to move it at the top of the route config.

Comment: Actually I just tried it, it is not conflicting in my end. What other routes do you have in your route config?

Comment: It conflicts with this one routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirRead", "fhir/{type}/{id}", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "Read" });

Comment: @Jefferson I updated the answer. For `FhirRead` route, you could add a routing constraint for `id` so that it only matches with integers.

Comment: What if I need to add this too routes.MapHttpRoute("FhirSearch", "fhir/Agent/List", new { controller = "Fhir", action = "AgentList" });

Comment: @Jefferson add that route on the top of your route config. And add this condition to your search action; `if(type == "AgentList"){
      return redirectToAction("AgentList");
   }` You 'll have 2 conditions now, one for AgentList and one for DiseaseList.